# Compute Statistical mode in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, statistics, hive, mode

How to calculate Statistical Mode in Hive?

Lets say to find the mode for a column in hive table.

Do we have any **inbuilt** functions for computing **Mode**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mention of a mode function in the [official docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) (see Built-in Aggregate Functions).

But the query to get the mode of a column is pretty simple, so a native function might not be necessary.

```
select age from (
    select age, count(age) as age_cnt
    from mytable
    group by age
    order by age_cnt desc
    limit 1
) t1
```

Comment: Showing "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:44 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'
". But this works: select age,count(age) as mode from test1 group by age sort by mode desc limit 1;
But I am trying to select only the age.

Comment: @SreeVeni see update, you can put your query in a derived table and then only select age from that table